# How to make  multiple "I need to.." web parts work on the same page

Tags: 2007

I am trying to create multiple "I need to.." web parts on the same page, but only the first created web part working.  The rest of all the web parts either don't respond after clicking the "GO" button or it goes to the first web part's selection, or even clicks on another web part.  I am using the Team Collaboration web page.  I tried to create a different custom list with a different web part and it did not work, and link to the same custom link with different filter settings which as well did not work.

Does anybody know some sort of tweaking or coding for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow [the instructions on John Roe's blog](http://blogs.officezealot.com/jrblog/archive/2007/10/08/i-need-to-web-part.aspx).

To summarise, for each additional web part:

1. Make a copy of the TATWP_jumpMenu function from Portal.js. Give it a unique name and add it to your page.
2. Update the web part reference to point to this unique function name (presumably with SharePoint Designer - this isn't mentioned).